# how to post laravel using Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use vue.js, I want to still store the date in a MySQL database when a post has been submitted, as well having the post show instantly like ajax(without the page refreshing).

Here is my code thus far, here is a rough sketch, I'm still trying to wrap my head around so please bear with me

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('title')
Dashboard
@endsection

@section('content')

<div class="dashboard eli-main">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-12">
                <h1>{{$user->username}}</h1>

                <h4>What do you have to say?</h4>
                <form action="{{ route('post.create') }}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" rows="5" placeholder="Your Post"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="mybtn2">Create Post</button>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
                </form>                   

                @foreach($posts as $post)                    

                <article class="post">
                    <h4>{{ $post->user->username }}</h4>
                    <p class="post-bod">
                        {{ $post->body }}
                    </p>
                    <div class="info">
                        made on {{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}
                    </div>
                </article>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script> 
var app = new Vue({
  el: 'post-bod',
  data: {
    post: body
  }
})
</script>

@endsection
```

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;

class PostController extends Controller
{
   public function getDashboard()
   {
     $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
     $cookie = cookie('saw-dashboard', true, 15);
     $users = User::all();
     $user = new User();
   //return view('dashboard', array('user'=> Auth::user()), compact('users'))->withCookie($cookie);

           return view('dashboard',array('user'=> Auth::user(), 'posts' => $posts,  compact('users')))->withCookie($cookie);
       }

    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'body' => 'required|max:1000'
        ]);

        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $message = 'There was an error';

        if($request->user()->posts()->save($post)){
            $message = 'Post Successfully Created';
        }

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getWelcome()
    {
        $user = new User();
        if (Auth::user()){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return view('welcome',  array('user'=> Auth::user()), compact('users') );
    }    

    public function userSignUp(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'

        ]);

        $email = $request['email'];
        $username = $request['username'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->username = $username;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard'); 
    }

    public function postSignin(Request $request)
    {
        $remember = $request->input('remember_me');

        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']], $remember )){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }    

    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use axios for `Post` or `Get` `request`, by the way, what version of Laravel did you used?

Comment: im using laravel 5.2, and can u elaborate a little more on axios

Comment: I'm using the latest version of **laravel** which is **5.4**, and the set up is already there, in **5.2** u can use the **vue-resource**, you need to install it locally via `npm`, please visit their documentation for more information [vue-resource-2] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-resource-2), [vue-resource github] (https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource)

Comment: there's no reason to force the usage of axios. Axios is just another http client like jQueries ajax or what used to be vue-resource. Use the lib the suits your needs. You will find enough examples for post and get requests for the corresponding library you chose